# Gazebo Callback not firing

Tags: c++, callback, swig, gazebo-simu

I am attempting to write a small library to interface Gazebo with Python (I tried using the pygazebo library and had no success). I am attempting to get the output from a camera and find April Tags and store the position data in a class variable using C++ code wrapped with SWIG to be used in Python. I had a standalone C++ application printing this data, but I have not been able to get it to work inside a class. From my testing the line `sub = node->Subscribe(IMAGE_TOPIC, &april::callback, this);` may be the problem. The code is included below.

gazeboApril.cpp

```
#include "gazeboApril.hpp"

april::april(void) {
    this->tag_size = (0.3 * (8.0 / 10.0)) / 2.0;
    apriltag_family_t *tf = tag36h11_create();
    this->td = apriltag_detector_create();
    apriltag_detector_add_family(this->td, tf);
    gazebo::client::setup();
    gazebo::transport::NodePtr node(new gazebo::transport::Node());
    gazebo::transport::SubscriberPtr sub;
    node->Init();
    sub = node->Subscribe(IMAGE_TOPIC, &april::callback, this);
}

void april::callback(ConstImageStampedPtr &msg) {
    int width;
    int height;
    char *data;

    width = (int) msg->image().width();
    height = (int) msg->image().height();
    data = new char[msg->image().data().length() + 1];

    memcpy(data, msg->image().data().c_str(), msg->image().data().length());
    cv::Mat image(height, width, CV_8UC3, data);

    cv::Mat gray;
    cv::cvtColor(image, gray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    image_u8_t im = { .width = gray.cols,
        .height = gray.rows,
        .stride = gray.cols,
        .buf = gray.data
    };
    zarray_t *detections = apriltag_detector_detect(td, &im);
    apriltag_detection *det;
    this->id.resize(zarray_size(detections));
    this->d.resize(zarray_size(detections));
    this->theta.resize(zarray_size(detections));
    for (int i = 0; i < zarray_size(detections); i++) {
        zarray_get(detections, i, &det);
        this->id.at(i) = det->id;
        matd_t *pose = homography_to_pose(det->H, -1108.77, 1108.77, 1280 / 2, 720 / 2);
        this->d.at(i) = this->tag_size * sqrt(pow(MATD_EL(pose, 0, 3), 2) + pow(MATD_EL(pose, 2, 3), 2));
        this->theta.at(i) = atan2(MATD_EL(pose, 0, 3), MATD_EL(pose, 2, 3));
    }
    delete data;
}

void april::stop(void) {
    gazebo::client::shutdown();
}
```

gazeboApril.hpp

```
#include <vector>

#include <gazebo/gazebo_client.hh>
#include <gazebo/msgs/msgs.hh>
#include <gazebo/transport/transport.hh>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#include "apriltag.h"
#include "tag36h11.h"
#include "common/homography.h"

#pragma once

#define IMAGE_TOPIC "/gazebo/default/pioneer3at/camera/link/camera/image"

class april {
public:
    april(void);
    void stop(void);
public:
    void callback(ConstImageStampedPtr &msg);
public:
    std::vector<int> id;
    std::vector<double> d;
    std::vector<double> theta;
protected:
    apriltag_detector_t *td;
    double tag_size;
};
```

gazeboApril.i

```
%module gazeboApril
%include "typemaps.i"
%include "std_vector.i"
namespace std {
    %template(IntVector) vector<int>;
    %template(DoubleVector) vector<double>;
};
%{
#include <Python.h>
#include "gazeboApril.hpp"
%}
%naturalvar april::id;
%naturalvar april::d;
%naturalvar april::theta;
%include "gazeboApril.hpp"
```

Comment: You will not get any meaningful answers if you do not provide some more information. What error do you get? Compile error or runtime error? Please provide as much information as possible.

Comment: I get no errors. It compiles and runs, but the callback function is never called.

Comment: Can you show the interface file you are using?

Comment: The question has been updated to include the SWIG interface file.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: If I remember correctly I moved away from a class structure which fixed my problem. I see that you added an answer. If that fixed the problem for you I will accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the return value of `Node::Subscribe` a local variable and keep it.

You only stay subscribed to the topic until the the destructor of the `SubscribePtr` is called. In your example, the `sub` variable is local to the constructor so you unsubscribe as soon as the constructor is left.